# Finding errors in primality tests?

Tags: prime-numbers, primality-test

How do you know when a primality test generates a number that is not prime?

Comment: When some other test proves the number composite.

Comment: In many algorithms you can assume $p$ is prime and go on working in the "pseudo" field $\Bbb Z/p$ till you encounter an $n\ne 0$ that has no inverse, at which point you can split $p$ into factors and continue assuming one of the factors is a prime, etc, till you get an actual prime.

Answer (score 1):

This is a long winded way of saying Daniel Fischer's comment "When some other test proves the number composite."

I'm guessing a bit as to what answer you're looking for.  If you're asking how we show that a given test has produced an incorrect answer, then it is exactly his answer -- run other tests until one indicates the number is composite, which would happen quickly.  Alternately we try to prove the primality, which (depending on the algorithm) will likely end up in a situation where the number is shown to be composite.  I suspect your answer is more of a question about confidence in probabilistic primality tests, which is the rest of this reply.

For large numbers, deterministic tests (i.e. primality tests that always correctly return one of "definitely composite" or "definitely prime") are slower than typically desired, and harder to code than compositeness tests.  This is all regarding numbers larger than 2^64, as there are fast deterministic methods for smaller numbers.  If you're especially paranoid, there are open source primality proving libraries -- they may or may not run fast enough for you (~50 milliseconds for 100 digits, ~15 seconds for 500 digits; this is for C+GMP and just giving an idea of the times).

A compositeness test typically reports one of "definitely composite" and "might be prime".  If there was a good fast way to know when the latter answer was wrong, then we'd be using it all the time.

We can think of a smoothness test (i.e. trial division by small numbers) as this sort of test, and indeed it is often the first thing done by primality tests in practice.  Testing divisibility by 2 is very fast and lets us answer "definitely composite" to half of all possible inputs.  Testing 3, 5, 7, 11, etc. quickly cuts out even more.  But unless we test all the primes up to $\sqrt{n}$, which is unfeasible with large $n$, we still have a number that "might be prime".

For Miller-Rabin tests, we know there is at *most* a 1/4 chance for a given number and base that the "might be prime" answer will be wrong.  Hence we can run multiple tests with different bases and reduce the chance of error to a truly miniscule level.  This is the most popular solution.

Another popular alternative is to run one base 2 Miller-Rabin test followed by a strong Lucas test.  The Lucas test is another compositeness test, but it has the interesting property of being anti-correlated to the base 2 Miller-Rabin test.  Numbers that produce incorrect answers for one test are more likely to produce correct answers for the other, and vice-versa.  It is still a "probable prime" test, but there are no known counterexamples so it works quite well.  See [BPSW on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baillie%E2%80%93PSW_primality_test).  Most math packages use a variant of this method for probable prime testing, as it is faster and more reliable than multiple M-R tests by themselves.

Basically one runs tests until a desired confidence level is reached.